# Is it possible to manage a single node using two different chef servers or two different organizations from single chef server

Tags: chef-infra

In my organization we are running two chef servers one is at enterprise level and other is at team level which is configured by me. All the nodes are bootstrapped by enterprise chef server before we use with our chef server. So, is it possible to avoid conflict and bootstrap the nodes with our chef server. Some suggested me to rename the `client.rb` file. `client.rb` and `client.pem` files are generated at bootstrap process so how can we manually copy them? and what will be the scenario if we were working from two different organizations from a single chef server?

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion is correct, the only way to do this is multiple non-overlapping configurations. You'll need to make your own bootstrap template for the second config set.